# Recursive function running multiple pipes

Tags: c, linux, recursion, piping

I'm trying to figure out why my function is not working.
I wrote a recursive function in c that executes piped commands supplied in an array of strings. but for some reason the command does not execute.

```
int run_piped_recursive(int index, char** arglist, int writefd){
    printf("entered recursive piping %d\n", index);
    while(index != 0){
        if(strcmp(arglist[index],"|") == 0){
            arglist[index] = NULL;

            int pipesfd[2];
            if(-1 == pipe(pipesfd)){
                printf("Error creating pipe when trying to run %s piped.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[index +1], errno, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }

            int child_pid = fork();
            if(child_pid < 0){
                printf("Error executing fork when trying to run %s piped.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[index +1], errno, strerror(errno));
                return -1;
            }

            if(child_pid == 0){
                close(pipesfd[0]);
                run_piped_recursive(--index, arglist, pipesfd[1]);
                exit(0);
            }
            else{
                if(writefd != 1) {
                    if (-1 == dup2(writefd, STDOUT_FILENO)) {
                        fprintf(stdout, "Error while trying to duplicate fd when running %s piped.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[index + 1], errno, strerror(errno));
                        return -1;
                    }
                    close(writefd);
                }

                close(pipesfd[1]);
                if(-1 == dup2(pipesfd[0], STDIN_FILENO)){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error while trying to duplicate fd when running %s piped.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[index +1], errno, strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
                close(pipesfd[0]);

                pthread_t wait_child_thread;
                if (-1 == pthread_create(&wait_child_thread, NULL, wait_pid_func, &child_pid)) { 
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error waiting for process with pid %d, running %s.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", child_pid, arglist[0], errno, strerror(errno));
                }


                if(-1 == execvp(arglist[index + 1], (arglist + index + 1) )){
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error running the command %s.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[0], errno, strerror(errno));
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
        index--;
    }
    if(1 != writefd) {
        printf("in if %d\n", writefd);
        if (-1 == dup2(writefd, STDOUT_FILENO)) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Error while trying to duplicate fd when running %s piped.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[index +1], errno,
               strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        close(writefd);
    }

    if(-1 == execvp(arglist[index], arglist )){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error running the command %s.\nerrno:%d\nError:%s\n", arglist[0], errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I've passed to the function the following arguments: the size of arglist minus 1(the index of the last string), arglist, STDOUT_FILENO.

When arglist is {"ls" "|" "grep" "a" }. The function seem to run but nothing is being printed to stdout I've also tried instead of creating a thread to wait for the child to finish I'm now using waitpid. it seemd that the process running "ls" and also the process running the "grep" finish (the program keeps running after this when debugging) but nothing is being printed to stdout.

Comment: What have you been able to learn from your debugging? Any ideas at all where things go wrong? If you need help, please provide a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In particular, we need to know exactly what parameters are being passed to the function (ie, how it is called).

Comment: And why are you creating a thread to seemingly wait for a process to complete? The normal way to do that is to call [`wait` or `waitpid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). If there is a reason for doing it with a thread then that needs to be explained to us.

Comment: I've passed to the function the following arguments: the size of arglist minus 1(the index of the last string), arglist,  STDOUT_FILENO.

Comment: When arglist is {"ls" "|" "grep" "a" }. The function seem to run but nothing is being printed to stdout

Comment: As requested, please provide an MCVE. You have described what you have done but we need to see the **exact code**. We can't tell for example whether you have passed the arguments in incorrectly. You have said "arglist is {"ls" "|" "grep" "a" }". But that's wrong as it is not a correctly intialised array. We can't tell if your code is really like that or you have just described it incorrectly. So please provide an MCVE - that is exact code with a `main` and all the function calls. Code that we can copy *as is* and run for ourselves.

Comment: `error: 'wait_pid_func' undeclared`